# Filter a drop down list to cascade from Anther drop down list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath-form

I have two fields. One is for Contract IDs and the other is CDRL Name Number.  In an InfoPath form,the client wants to choose, from a drop down list, a specific Contract ID that will only load items directly connected to that particular ID in another drop down list (CDRL Name Number).  Everything I have tried keeps failing. What is the best solution to meet this requirement?

Thanks,
James

Comment: Take a look at this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233338/infopath-and-cascading-dropdowns

Comment: Also try this:  https://www.salamandersoft.co.uk/blog/implement-cascading-drop-down-for-forms-in-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you wantto create cascading dropdown Fields in InfoPath.

InfoPath 2013 Web Browser- Creating Cascading Dropdown Fields with no Code for your reference:

http://msreddysharepoint.blogspot.in/2012/12/infopath-2013-web-browser-creating.html